# Sanitize Angular JS with double curly bracers

Tags: angularjs, ngsanitize

I am trying to display html that i got from server. Example of server response is something like this: `'<p>Hello Mister {{first_name}}</p>'`;

So, in my controller I stored this response in $scope variable like this:

```
$scope.centralText.text = $sce.trustAsHtml(response_from_server)
```

On HTML side, I made binding:

```
<div ng-bind-html="centralText.text"></div>
```

and that results "Hello Mister {{first_name}}".

What I was making to accomplish is passing generic value for variable $scope.first_name to server response html.

Example:

```
$scope.first_name = "Luis Figo";
```

Output:

Hello Mister Luis Figo

Just to be clear:
the html `<p>Hello Mister {{first_name}}</p>` is just dummy example, its can be anything else, so I couldn't hardcode.

Thanks for help!

**Update**

Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PN1WhYbU1wjA55scPD0M?p=preview) with my example.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the [$compile service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) to compile the html against your scope.

```
$compile($sce.trustAsHtml(response_from_server))($scope);
```

Comment: Already tried. I just created plunker, so please check my update.